# How to install iTunes on Ubuntu Desktop 18.04 LTS?

Tags: windows, itunes

Please, how to install Ubuntu Desktop 18.04 LTS on iTunes software and other Windows application software?

Answer (score 2):

It's wine and playonlinux. Open terminal. Type

```
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt install wine-stable  
sudo apt-get install playonlinux
```

Then open up firefox and go to this download link https://www.apple.com/itunes/download/ click the 64 or 32 bit download link

wait until its finished

back in the terminal type

```
playonlinux
```

when play on linux has opened click the (install +) then type in Itunes, select it, and click install follow the installer as you see fit.

sign in and should be working i have a website tutorial that can be used step 3 and 6 did not work for myself.

https://www.wikihow.tech/Download-iTunes-for-Linux